# Why is my FPS character turning to 0 on the Y axis when I have it set to 90

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, rotation

I am working on a FPS controller and for some reason when I hit play the player keeps rotating to 0 on the y axis when I have rotated it to 90. I am pretty sure it has to do with the camera if that helps narrow things down.

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
Animator anim;
float RotateX;
float RotateY;
public static bool GamePaused;

[SerializeField]
[Header("Game Objects")]
public GameObject Camera;

[Header("Movement Settings")]
public float WalkSpeed = 5.0f;


[Header("Rotation Settings")]
public float RorationSpeed = 3.0f;
public float MaxYAxis = 60.0f;
public float MinYAxis = -48.0f;

private void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void Update()
{
    Rotation();
    Movement();
}

void Rotation()
{
    RotateX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * RorationSpeed;
    RotateY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * RorationSpeed;
    RotateY = Mathf.Clamp(RotateY, MinYAxis, MaxYAxis);
    Camera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(-RotateY, 0f, 0f);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, RotateX, 0f);
}

void Movement()
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * WalkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * WalkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first call of `Update` the `GetAxis("Mouse X")` returns `0` so

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, RotateX, 0f);
```

resets the rotation to `0, 0, 0`.

---

You should rather simply store the initial rotation

```
private void Awake()
{
    RotateX = transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
    RotateY = Camera.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.x;
    if (RotateY > 180)
    {
        RotateY = -(360 - RotateY);
    }
}

private void Rotation()
{
    RotateX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * RorationSpeed;
    RotateY -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * RorationSpeed;
    RotateY = Mathf.Clamp(RotateY, MinYAxis, MaxYAxis);
    Camera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(RotateY, 0f, 0f);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, RotateX, 0f);
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works really well. I changed the camera transform in your response back to -RotateY otherwise when you look up the mouse goes down.

Comment: this should be already the case by using `RotateY -= ...` note the `-`

Comment: I completely missed that.

Answer (score 1):

It actually has to do with your `Rotation` method.
The game will call the `Update` method at the start, which will call the `Rotation` method. In there you update the values of the rotation which at the start of the game will be 0.0 and no movement on the input axis is made so no rotation at the beginning, finally you update your rotations with 0.0 values, resetting what you set in the Editor.

What you would like to do is rotate of `RotateY` or `RotateX` degrees the camera or controller. Something like:

```
void Rotation()
{
    RotateX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * RorationSpeed;
    RotateY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * RorationSpeed;
    RotateY = Mathf.Clamp(RotateY, MinYAxis, MaxYAxis);
    Camera.transform.Rotate(new Vecto3(-RotateY, 0f, 0f));
    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0f, RotateX, 0f));
}
```

Comment: @Sealeas It just makes me spin around in circles in ever increasing speed.

Comment: Oh! My mistake, I was increasing the rotation at every update. I updated the answer. In this way you may even just use local variables inside the Rotation method instead of class properties since you don't need to store te value.

Comment: It works, but now the restrictions on the camera do not work.

Comment: That's right. Now you need to get the current rotation from the transform and clamp that value, `RotationY`is only the rotation that happens between frames and not the current rotation of the object.